# Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers. If $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < -1$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I came up with the following proof for the theorem in the title:

*Proof.*
Suppose $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$. Suppose $a \ge -1$.Then it follows that $-1 \le a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$.Suppose $a = -1$. Then it follows immediately from $a < \frac{1}{a}$ that $-1 < -1$ which is false. Thus $a \ne -1$. Suppose $-1 < a < 0$.Then it follows from $a < \frac{1}{a}$ that $a^{2} > 1$. One can infer from $a^{2} > 1$ that $a < -1$. But this contradicts with the fact that $a \ge -1$. Hence $a \le -1$ or $a \ge 0$. Finally, suppose $a > 0$. It follows from $a < \frac{1}{a}$ that $a^{2} < 1$ and consequently $0 < a < 1$. Since $0 < a < 1$, one can infer that $b > 1$ from $\frac{1}{a} < b$. But this contradicts with the fact that $b < 1$ which can be inferred from $b^{2} < 1$ which followed from $b < \frac{1}{b}$. Hence $a \le 0$. Since all possible cases for $a \ge -1$ have been exhausted, it is impossible for $a \ge -1$.Thus $a < -1$.

In case $a < -1$, it follows immediately that $a < \frac{1}{a}$. Since $a < -1$, one can infer from $\frac{1}{a} < b$ that $b > -1$. Suppose $-1 < b < 0$. It follows from $b < \frac{1}{b}$ that $b^{2} > 1$ and consequently $b < -1$. But this contradicts with the assumption that $-1 < b < 0$. Hence $b \le -1$ or $b \ge 0$. Suppose $b > 0$. It follows from $b < \frac{1}{b}$ that $b^{2} < 1$. Only $b$ in the interval $0 < b < 1$ satisfies $b^{2} < 1$. It follows that the only intervals of $a$ and $b$ which satisfies $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ is $a < -1$ and $0 < b < 1$ respectively. Therefore if $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < -1$. QED

I have two questions reagarding my proof. First, can this be regarded as a proof, and secondly if it is a proof, can I end my proof after exhausting all possible cases for $a \ge -1$?

Comment: Off point : posting very hard to read.  Easier: $~a < 1/a~$ only has two possibilities: either $~0 < a < 1,~$ or $~a < -1.~$  The 1st possibility leads to contradiction, since it implies $~1 < 1/a < b,~$ which is impossible, since $~b < 1/b.~$

Comment: 1) yes, 2) yes.

Comment: Per @user2661923, I’d suggest you look at the graph of $y=1/x$ and examine the portion(s) of that curve where $x<1/x$. HINT: It’s the intersection of the graph with the half plane satisfying $x<y$.